# HTML5 border not fitting in <div> to margin-right

Tags: html, css

I took over a mobile app with AngularJS and Ionic 1.x (yes, old - I know). Inside this `<ion-content>` I would like to have the part of the email always being 10px away from the right border; independent of the media size. See screenshot in case please.
[image]

Here is the relevant part of my .html-file:

```
<ion-content scroll="true" class="pdfsmtp">
    <h5 class="left">1. Email-Adresse:</h5>
    <div class="middle">
         <button ng-click="changeEmail(0)" ng-controller="EmailsCtrl"
           class="button button-small button-block button-outline">{{emails[0]}}</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <h5 class="left">2. Email-Adresse:</h5>
   (...)
</ion-content>
```

Here is how the .css-file looks like:

```
.pdfsmtp 
{
  .button-bar 
  {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .left
  {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
  }

  .middle
  {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .button-icon
  {
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: white;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 736px) and (max-width: 1023px) 
{
  .players.modal 
  {
    top: 12%;
    bottom: 12%;
  }
}
```

My question is: How to have my goal achieved? I tried several approaches, but none worked so far...

Comment: Would you like someone@somewhere.com to be 10px away from the right border but touching the left border?

Comment: Left border? No. I would like to have it being away instead from fields like "1. Email-Adresse" in a flexible manner; depending on the media size. Right border: 10px would be okay; yes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this?

```css
button{
  width: max-content;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<button>abcz@xyz.com</button>
<br/><br/>
<button>lonnnggg_email@xyz.com</button>
<br/><br/>
<button>mediumemail@h.com</button>
```

Comment: I added it beneath .pdfsmtp, but things have not changed in regards to my issue. Only the font-size is different now ;-).

Comment: I now have found a different a different way using Ionic built-in features. Question can be archived.